# C# Capturing the output of a process asynchronous is always null

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Currently I'm trying to capture the output of a console application.
If I use the `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` method, I can capture the output correctly, but if I use `OutputDataReceived`, the event is never called.

My code:

```
Process testProcess = new Process();
testProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "teste.exe";
testProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
testProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
testProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
testProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
testProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

testProcess.Start();
StreamWriter myStreamWriter = testProcess.StandardInput;
myStreamWriter.Write("a"); // press any key to continue

// var output = testProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); // this works all the times

StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
testProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
  // never raised
  if (e.Data != null)
    output.AppendLine("'" + e.Data + "'");
};

testProcess.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Comment: try using `Process.BeginOutputReadLine();` also do a google search on the documentation this should start an Async process if I am not mistaken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [documentation of `OutputDataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx), you must call `testProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()`.

You also might have to call `testProcess.Start()` after you set the `OutputDataReceived` event, as the example does.